# how to get the last address of an ARM image?

Tags: gcc, arm, arm64, linaro

I have a bare metal stand alone elf image compiled with linaro gcc. I need to find out the last address in that image. I tried doing this with `objcopy -O ihex` , and writing a small script to parse the ihex output, but this fails if the addresses exceed the 2G address space. So - how can I find out what is the last address in the image?

This is for an arm V8 64 bit architecture chip.

can objcopy be used for this, or should I use something else from the linaro toolchain? objdump maybe?

any help would be appriciated!

Comment: @artlessnoise - ok, got it done by parsing readelf output. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`objdump` and `readelf` can both display section summaries. `objdump -h` and `readelf -S` seem to be the proper options.

For example,

```
$ objdump -h boot_flag

boot_flag:     file format elf32-littlearm

Sections:
Idx Name          Size      VMA       LMA       File off  Algn
  0 .note.gnu.build-id 00000024  000080b4  000080b4  000000b4  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  1 .text         00000310  000080d8  000080d8  000000d8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, CODE
  2 .rodata       00000030  000083e8  000083e8  000003e8  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, READONLY, DATA
  3 .data         00000004  00010418  00010418  00000418  2**2
                  CONTENTS, ALLOC, LOAD, DATA
  4 .comment      0000003a  00000000  00000000  0000041c  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
  5 .ARM.attributes 0000002d  00000000  00000000  00000456  2**0
                  CONTENTS, READONLY
```

And...

```
$ readelf -S boot_flag
There are 8 section headers, starting at offset 0x4d0:

Section Headers:
  [Nr] Name              Type            Addr     Off    Size   ES Flg Lk Inf Al
  [ 0]                   NULL            00000000 000000 000000 00      0   0  0
  [ 1] .note.gnu.build-i NOTE            000080b4 0000b4 000024 00   A  0   0  4
  [ 2] .text             PROGBITS        000080d8 0000d8 000310 00  AX  0   0  4
  [ 3] .rodata           PROGBITS        000083e8 0003e8 000030 01 AMS  0   0  4
  [ 4] .data             PROGBITS        00010418 000418 000004 00  WA  0   0  4
  [ 5] .comment          PROGBITS        00000000 00041c 00003a 01  MS  0   0  1
  [ 6] .ARM.attributes   ARM_ATTRIBUTES  00000000 000456 00002d 00      0   0  1
  [ 7] .shstrtab         STRTAB          00000000 000483 00004b 00      0   0  1
Key to Flags:
  W (write), A (alloc), X (execute), M (merge), S (strings)
  I (info), L (link order), G (group), T (TLS), E (exclude), x (unknown)
  O (extra OS processing required) o (OS specific), p (processor specific)
```

Show some section information for an ARM926 static binary.  Of interest are the `VMA`, `LMA`, `Size` and `Addr` fields.  Extract them and sort and then add the `Size` to the final value.